# jQuery: autoclick link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this question has been asked many times before and there are countless answers for it but the issue that I have is that I have no idea why I cannot autoclick a link on page load!

I have used the same process over 20 times before without any issue but now it doesn't work...

Here is a fiddle with the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/1xy0f291/

and this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert('hello');
  $('#pop').trigger('click');
   $('#pop').click();
});
```

anyone has any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @guradio is that a new thing then? like i said, I have used the exact same process over 20 times before without any issue!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically `$().click()` will invoke the click event handler bound with it. Not the natural click.

For invoking the natural click you have to access the plain node object and call its `click()` function,

```
 $('#pop')[0].click();
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/1xy0f291/1/)

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
document.getElementById('pop').click()
```

updated fiddle :  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1xy0f291/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Add some small code fix, use [eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
 $('#pop').click(); -> $('#pop').eq(0).click();
 $('#pop').trigger('click'); -> $('#pop').eq(0).trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this document.getElementById('pop').click()